# Treat a Character as a variable

Tags: string, r, variables, character, converters

Suppose I have the following code

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-'a'
```

Now I was to treat the string in 'b' as the variable 'a' 
when I input it into some function or operation.
Like imagine that "treat.as.variable()" was a real function it would do this:

```
treat.as.variable(b)+c(1,2,4)
[1] 2 4 7
```

is there a function like this, predefined?
Or a way to do this in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `get` function

```
> get(b) + c(1,2,4)
[1] 2 4 7
```